# SafariViewController: How to grab OAuth token from URL?

Tags: swift, facebook, oauth, swift2, sfsafariviewcontroller

Trying to use Facebook OAuth with the SafariViewController. First I open the authURL with SafariViewController, which if the user is logged in to Facebook on Safari, will redirect them and return an OAuth URL with the token for that specific service, e.g. Instagram

RESPONSE: https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=BLAHTOKENRESPONSE&expires_in=5114338

When SafariViewController has redirected I want to grab the response URL and store it so I can grab the token. Here is my code:

```
import SafariServices

let kSafariViewControllerCloseNotification = "kSafariViewControllerCloseNotification"

import UIKit

// facebook OAuth URL for service
let authURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=3627644767&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=basic_info,email,public_profile,user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_friends,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_relationship_details&response_type=token")

class ViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    var safariVC: SFSafariViewController?
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        safariVC = SFSafariViewController(URL: authURL!)
        safariVC!.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(safariVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // not firing the safariLogin function below
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.safariLogin(_:)), name: kSafariViewControllerCloseNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func safariLogin(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("Safari Login call")
        // get the url form the auth callback
        let url = notification.object as! NSURL
        print(url)
        self.safariVC!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        print("application call")
        // just making sure we send the notification when the URL is opened in SFSafariViewController
        if (sourceApplication == "com.application.SafariViewTest") {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kSafariViewControllerCloseNotification, object: url)
            return true
        }
        return true
    }  

}
```

It opens the authURL and redirects to the correct response URL, but the observer does not fire the safariLogin function to grab the URL. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Figured it out. Some of the methods were pre iOS 9 and now deprecated. I also had the `application` function in the ViewController I created when it should have been defined in the `AppDelagate.swift`. For example

**Added at end of AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

        print("app: \(app)")
        // print OAuth response URL
        print("url: \(url)")
        print("options: \(options)")

        if let sourceApplication = options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] {
            if (String(sourceApplication) == "com.testApp.Incognito") {
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kSafariViewControllerCloseNotification, object: url)
                return true
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import SafariServices

let kSafariViewControllerCloseNotification = "kSafariViewControllerCloseNotification"

// facebook OAuth URL
let authURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=3627644767&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=basic_info,email,public_profile,user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_friends,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_relationship_details&response_type=token")

class ViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    var safariVC: SFSafariViewController?
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        safariVC = SFSafariViewController(URL: authURL!)
        safariVC!.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(safariVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.safariLogin(_:)), name: kSafariViewControllerCloseNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func safariLogin(notification: NSNotification) {
        // get the url from the auth callback
        let url = notification.object as! NSURL
        // Finally dismiss the Safari View Controller with:
        self.safariVC!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    } 

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func safariViewControllerDidFinish(controller: SFSafariViewController) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in
            print("You just dismissed the login view.")
        }
    }

    func safariViewController(controller: SFSafariViewController, didCompleteInitialLoad didLoadSuccessfully: Bool) {
        print("didLoadSuccessfully: \(didLoadSuccessfully)")

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little lost at how you got the redirect url to call the application function? I want to do something similar and copied what you did but I'm not able to get SFSafariViewController to call back the application function

Comment: Uhm... you just took code from http://strawberrycode.com/blog/sfsafariviewcontroller-and-oauth-the-instagram-example/ without accrediting it ...

Answer (score 37):

## iOS 12+

iOS 12 Beta already deprecates SFAuthenticationSession (see below) in favor of [ASWebAuthenticationSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession). It looks like it is used exactly the same  way but requires the new [AuthenticationServices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices) framework.

## iOS 11

iOS 11 introduced [SFAuthenticationSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfauthenticationsession) which is so much easier to handle. Given its nature this beta API may still change but there already are a couple of examples ([1](https://github.com/dvdhpkns/SFAuthenticationSession-example/blob/master/SFAuthenticationSessionExample/SFAuthenticationSessionExample/ViewController.swift), [2](https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/ios-11-privacy-and-single-sign-on-6291687a2ccc)) on the internet. First, you need a completion handler that is called with the result of the authentication request:

```
let completion : SFAuthenticationSession.CompletionHandler = { (callBack:URL?, error:Error?) in
    guard error == nil, let successURL = callBack else {
        return
    }

    let oauthToken = NSURLComponents(string: (successURL.absoluteString))?.queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "oauth_token"}).first

    // Do what you have to do...
}
```

Then you simply create a SFAuthenticationSession and start it.

```
let authURL = "https://the.service.you/want/toAuthorizeWith?..."
let scheme = "YOURSCHEME://"
let authSession = SFAuthenticationSession(url: authURL, callbackURLScheme: scheme, completionHandler: completion)
authSession.start()
```

## iOS 10 and before

As some have noted in the comments, the accepted answer is incomplete and won't work on its own. When strolling through Strawberry Code's blog post one can find a [link to the related GitHub project](https://github.com/strawberrycode/SafariOauthLogin). That project's `README.MD` explains a crucial part of the setup, namely adding the redirect URI to `Info.plist`. So the whole thing goes down like this:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

   if let sourceApplication = options[.sourceApplication] {
       if (String(describing: sourceApplication) == "com.apple.SafariViewService") {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("CallbackNotification"), object: url)
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

Register for the notification to call your handler in some sensible place. I'd recommend not doing it in `viewDidLoad()` but only before you are actually presenting the `SFSafariViewController`.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(safariLogin(_:)), name: Notification.Name("CallbackNotification"), object: nil)
let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(URL: authURL)
safariVC.delegate = self
self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And then remove the observance in the handler:

```
@objc func safariLogin(_ notification : Notification) {

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("CallbackNotification"), object: nil)

    guard let url = notification.object as? URL else {
        return
    }

    // Parse url ...

}
```

Remember that the user is able to dismiss the `SFSafariViewController` by tapping the `Done` button, so be sure to adopt the `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate` protocol and remove the observance like this as well:

```
func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("CallbackNotification"), object: nil)
}
```

**Info.plist**

To make it all work you need to add your redirect URI scheme to `Info.plist`:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.YOUR.BUNDLE.IDENTIFIER</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>YOURSCHEME</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Of course YOURSCHEME has to match the scheme of the redirect URI you registered with the web service you're trying to oAuthorizing with.

Comment: Hey, I did like you wrote for iOS 10 and below including adding a scheme. But for some reason, `AppDelegate`'s method is not being called. Do you have any idea why? My schema looks like `https://example.com` redirect leads to `https://example.com/redirect`. From my point of view, this should work, right?