# open url function not called in AppDelegate when trying to grab token from oauth url

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, strava

I'm trying to implement an OAuth flow on iOS - Swift 3, in order to query a REST API ([Strava](https://strava.github.io/api/)).

I do this in my VC handling the auth flow:

```
@IBAction func tappedStartAuth(_ sender: Any) {

    let authUrlStr = "http://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=12345&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost/exchange_token&approval_prompt=force&scope=view_private,write"

    // but instead 12345 I have my real cientID of course

    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:authUrlStr)!)

    // Did not work with SFVC either:
    //safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: authUrlStr)!)
    //safariViewController?.delegate = self
    //present(safariViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

In my AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    print("opened url, [code] checking should follow, but this won't get called")

    // would do some stuff here...

    return true
}
```

And I added my url scheme in the plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>org.my.bundle.id</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>localhost</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

**However, I can't get the `application(_:open:options:)` function in my AppDelegate to be called.**

(The browser is popped up allright, I can login to Strava, and I see that the valid URL is returned including the access token in the "code=..." piece, that I would like to extract, but I can't move on to that part.)

I've tried:

- with the built-in Safari browser (leaving the app)
- with SFSafariViewController
- on iOS 9 instead of 11 (I know that on 11 apple has introduced
  SFAuthenticationSession, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42443062). I have not looked
  into that yet, but I would need my app on pre-11 too).
- My `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` function is
  returning true and I'm not implementing
  `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` as described in the discussion part of the [function's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application).

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it was actually a mixture of things that I did not notice...

1. The URL I was trying to use there was wrong: It should not be
   `http://` but `yourApp://` since you want yourApp to handle the
   callback.  On some forum I read that Strava only allows http redirect
   uris, which made me try it that way, but that's actually wrong, as
   [the documentation](https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/) states:

> URL to which the user will be redirected with the authorization code, must be to the callback domain associated with the application, or its sub-domain, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are white-listed.

And we got to the next thing, namely:

2. You should check what you name your application on the Strava admin page at Settings/My Api Application.
   Following the yourApp example, it should be something like this:
   [image: Strava My Api Application setup]

(My mistake was, that I did not provide a valid/matching callback domain.)

3. Finally, your plist file should be also set accordingly:

```xml
        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                <string>com.yourdomain.yourApp</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>yourApp</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
```

And it works like charm: it does not actually matter if it's iOS 9 or 11, or you use `SFSafariViewController` VS you leave the app with `UIApplication.shared.openURL()` etc...

Good luck ;)

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Just to add: when you are creating your URL to access the API: `&redirect_uri=yourApp://localhost`