# Authorization handling for Azure AD for webview for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-active-directory

We have XF iOS app, where user logins via ADAL library to access API endpoints behind Azure AD.
We need to open url in web-view (that is also behind Azure AD) and handle authentication automatically.
Tried to use default webview control, that allows to set request headers for each request for authentication (since ADAL requires to get token for each resource): via custom NSUrlProtocol and NSUrlConnectionDataDelegate. It worked, but website is quite heavy and performed really bad in webview.

After we switched to SFSafariViewController - performance is great, but we can't handle authentication. So users need to login explicitly.

The question is: is there any way to handle authentication automatically via SFSafariViewController?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42443062/8187800 may help.

Comment: Sorry, seems like it won't help in this specific case.

Comment: We are also facing similar issue, @MykhailGalushko, can you please guide us how you have pass Azure AD authorization in Custom Web view? Thanks in advance

Comment: @BharatLeel we implemented iOS web-view with custom protocol to handle all responses to add authorization header to load internal resources