# iOS 12 - AppAuth redirect URL not trigger AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, redirect, appauth

I am using `AppAuth` on my code.

I manage to authenticate successful , but when the `SFSafariViewController` `gets dismiss from my Controller` , the redirect url does not trigger the `AppDelegate` `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`

The redirect URL is my Bundle Identifier name : BundleIdentifier://authenticate

I have setup in info.plist url Schemes and url identifier which they have the same name.

When I run my code setting a break point on this func I can see my redirect url correct for `standarizedURL` and `standarizedRedirectURL`

```
- (BOOL)shouldHandleURL:(NSURL *)URL {
  NSURL *standardizedURL = [URL standardizedURL];
  NSURL *standardizedRedirectURL = [_request.redirectURL standardizedURL];

    return OIDIsEqualIncludingNil(standardizedURL.scheme, standardizedRedirectURL.scheme) &&
    OIDIsEqualIncludingNil(standardizedURL.user, standardizedRedirectURL.user) &&
    OIDIsEqualIncludingNil(standardizedURL.password, standardizedRedirectURL.password) &&
    OIDIsEqualIncludingNil(standardizedURL.host, standardizedRedirectURL.host) &&
    OIDIsEqualIncludingNil(standardizedURL.port, standardizedRedirectURL.port) &&
    OIDIsEqualIncludingNil(standardizedURL.path, standardizedRedirectURL.path);
```

But when AppAuth finishes the authentication and I have an `access token` , `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` doesn't get triggered.

Any idea why?

Here is my code

```
class func signInAuth(discoveryURLstr: String,presenter : UIViewController,completionHandler: @escaping ( (OIDAuthState?,Error?) -> () )){

        guard let discoveruURL = URL(string: discoveryURLstr) else{
            completionHandler(nil,AuthErrors.InvalidDiscoveryURL)
            return
        }

        appAuthDiscoverConfiguration(discoveryURL: discoveruURL) { (configurationFile, error) in

            guard let configurationFile = configurationFile else {
                completionHandler(nil,AuthErrors.InvalidConfigurationFile)
                return
            }

            let authRequest = appAuthRequest(configurationFile: configurationFile)

             self.appAuthenticationSession = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: authRequest, presenting: presenter, callback: { (state, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    //self.authState = nil
                    completionHandler(nil,error)
                    return
                }

                if let state = state {
                    self.authState = state
                    completionHandler(state,nil)

                }else{
                    completionHandler(nil,AuthErrors.InvalideState)
                }
            })

        }


    }

    class func appAuthDiscoverConfiguration(discoveryURL : URL, completionHandler: @escaping ((OIDServiceConfiguration?,Error?) -> ())) {

        OIDAuthorizationService.discoverConfiguration(forDiscoveryURL: discoveryURL) { (configuration, error) in

            if let error = error {
                completionHandler(nil,error)
                return
            }else{
                guard let configurationFile = configuration else {
                    completionHandler(nil,AuthErrors.InvalidConfigurationFile)
                    return
                }
                completionHandler(configurationFile,nil)
            }

        }

    }

    class func appAuthRequest(configurationFile : OIDServiceConfiguration) -> OIDAuthorizationRequest{

        return OIDAuthorizationRequest(configuration: configurationFile, clientId: AppAuthConstants.clientId, clientSecret: nil, scope: AppAuthConstants.scope, redirectURL: AppAuthConstants.redirectURL, responseType: AppAuthConstants.responseType, state: nil, nonce: nil, codeVerifier: nil, codeChallenge: nil, codeChallengeMethod: nil, additionalParameters: AppAuthConstants.additionalParameters)
    }
```

Comment: Is your server call this url: The redirect URL is my Bundle Identifier name : BundleIdentifier://authenticate after authentication?

Comment: Server doesn’t call this url. This is the redirect url. I set redirect url on my request as you can see . And redirect url is bundleidentifier://authenticate

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 12, App-Auth uses `ASWebAuthenticationSession`, and on iOS 11, it uses the now-deprecated `SFAuthenticationSession` instead of requiring the app to support handling the redirect manually.  To support earlier versions of iOS, you still need your code in the `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` method.

For reference, you can see what AppAuth is doing under the covers [here](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/687a30e6957bef3e3b36f9cdb7fb45ec5c758bfd/Source/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m#L59).  Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42443062/3867132) is a great answer that explains how to generically get an OAuth token on iOS without using AppAuth.